# Angular animation on an isolated scope element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that exposes a single function `notify` to the parent scope. The rest of the directive needs to remain private.

```
angular.module('my-module')
    .directive('notifier', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace : true,
            template : '<div n-notify="notify">{{message}}</div>',
            scope : {
                message : '@',
                nNotify : '='
            },
            link : function($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.nNotify = function(message)
                {
                    $scope.message = message;
                    element.addClass('notify-this');
                };
            }
        }
    })

    .animate('.notify-this', function() {
        return {
            addClass : function(el, class, done) {
                // Code here
            },
            removeClass : function(el, class, done) {
                // Code here
            }
        }
    });
```

When the directive is not in an isolated scope the animation works fine. When I isolate the scope, the animation does not apply when the class is added. How can I get the animation working inside an isolated scope when using javascript for the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In isolated scopes classes need to be applied with the `$animate` service. Adding a class with jQlite, jQuery or vanilla JS will not work.

```
.directive('notifier', ['$animate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace : true,
        template : '<div n-notify="notify">{{message}}</div>',
        scope : {
            message : '@',
            nNotify : '='
        },
        link : function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.nNotify = function(message)
            {
                $scope.message = message;
                $animate.addClass(el, 'notify-this');
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```